# How to change our success community url?

Tags: customer-community

Currently our success community resides at the following url:

https://abc.force.com/success

I have looked at the documentation and I can see how we would change this url but my question is how do we handle the switchover. If somebody has our above url bookmarked, how do we ensure that they will get redirected to our new url? Also is there any downtime involved in the switch of urls?

Also we have a knowledge base residing at http://knowledge.abc.com. Can you please provide best practice or advice on how we go about relocating this to a new domain.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article in Salesforce to get this done, follow this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205653&language=en_US&type=1), its pretty straight forward. It explains for Site.com but it is similar for force.com sites.

There is no downtime as such, for me it switched over in about 5-10 minutes. If there are any hardcoded urls like /SiteName/Page_Name then you would need to change them to just /Page_Name.

You would need to add CNAME entries on abc.com DNS, something which you need to check out of Salesforce. And another thing is that this works only in Production orgs, not in Sandbox or Developer edition.

All the best!